# Upper leg getting too big

Tags: legs, clothing

My upper leg seems to be developing nicely but now the pants don't fit. It's either:

1 The waist fits but the quad-hamstring diameter causes the pants to choke my leg, usually leading to a rip under the butt or wearing between the legs, or

2 The legs fit and the waist doesn't leaving me with a belt line that looks like a parachute.

I'm not really the kind of person to wear track pants outside of the gym and prefer jeans and formal pants. 
So my question is has anyone found a solution to this problem and what kind pants should I consider buying next?

Comment: Levi's Denizen 232 line is good. They're the only jeans that I've found to be comfortable for me in the same situation you're in. Formal pants can be purchased in a size larger than you need and then altered down your correct size.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a recommendation for buying pants.

Comment: Lol.....that's good news, isn't it? :) You might be able to find some jeans type that fit your body; you'll have to be patient though *(and probably choose between tight waist or tight thighs).* Your slacks would most likely need alterations unless they're custom-made for you.

Comment: It's a problem. I used to have to buy to fit my legs/rear (cycling and swimming), and then have the waist tailored. Suits were the worst, most have a 6" difference from waist to shoulders, mine was 17".

Answer (score 1):

Stretch jeans! Also has the added benefit of highlighting the results of your leg work. ;)

Other than that, get a pair that fits your upper legs and take them to a tailor for adjustments.

Comment: Stretch jeans has been my best experience thus but they still wear away between the legs.

Comment: You mean because your thighs are rubbing against each other?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: Sorry mate, haven't found any solution for that yet. Except to buy not too expensive jeans and change them when they're worn.